# Screenshot Safari from Share Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios-app-extension

Is it possible to perform a screenshot of the current visible zone of the webview in Safari from a Share Extension? I could use windows, but UIApplication isn't supported on extensions so I can't access to that window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't since UIApplication can't be reached from an extension. You cannot get the first UIWindow, which is the Safari layer, so you have to play with the Javascript preprocessing file that the extensions have. So just create a Javascript file that, when sent to Safari, generates a base64 string with the current visible zone image data. Take that string through the kUTTypePropertyList identifier in your extension. Since that should be NSData, generate the UIImage from there, by using `+imageWithData`. That is what you're looking for, without having to load the page again, preventing a second load and a bad image if the webpage requires of a login.

Comment: @skozz Hi, I am trying to use html2canvas to generate the image but how to return this to the extension. I also tried to return document.body but it does not work.

Comment: I manage to capture the screen with html2canvas library, but the extension crash... seems to be some timeout error when the js processing takes too long

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't unless you invoke the API you need dynamically, and even so you might run into context permission issues and app store approval issues.

An alternative might be passing the current Safari URL to your extension, load it using a hidden UIWebView and render this view into an UIImage but you will loose the current visible zone information...

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing, but I can't get the current visible zone of the user and I've to load the same webpage twice (safari and my hidden UIWebView). I guess this is the part they didn't tell us about Extensibility, how limited it is.

Comment: This approach will also fail for web pages where the user has to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: So the below works in the Simulator but does *not* work on the device. I'm presently looking for a solution as well.

You can't get just the visible area of Safari, but you *can* get a screenshot with a little ingenuity. The following method captures a screenshot from a ShareViewController.

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage
{
    // Get the "screenshot" view.
    let view = UIScreen.mainScreen().snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)

    // Add the screenshot view as a subview of the ShareViewController's view.
    self.view.addSubview(view);

    // Now screenshot *this* view.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Finally, remove the subview.
    view.removeFromSuperview()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approved way to capture the screenshot of a webpage in a share extension:

```
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        [itemProvider loadPreviewImageWithOptions:@{NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey: [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(60.0f, 60.0f)]} completionHandler:^(UIImage * item, NSError * _Null_unspecified error) {
            // Set the size to that desired, however,
            // Note that the image 'item' returns will not necessarily by the size that you requested, so code should handle that case.
            // Use the UIImage however you wish here.
        }];
    }
}
```